# how to parse MDNS response?

Tags: c, parsing, protocols, network-protocols, mdns

We have some devices (Like IP cameras) on network. I am writing APIs in C to find these cameras. These cameras support multicast DNS query. I have the format for query, but I do not have the general response format. so that I could write API that can parse MDNS query responses. Can someone have MDNS parser, preferably implemented in C or exact format of the response. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mDNS responses are formatted as per standard DNS responses, described in [RFC1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).

See also the Multicast DNS [RFC6762](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6762.txt), in particular sections 16, 17, 18 and 19, which cover some differences with Unicast DNS (eg. longer messages are allowed, a wider character set is allowed).

Comment: Beware that mDNS has some differences to standard DNS, such as character set. Page 51 of RFC6762 has a summary of these differences.